# Is there a language where you can get unlimited high double variables?

Tags: variables, editor, programming-languages

I'm having some fun with extremely high variables. Fx I've tried to find high primenumbers. My last try was with 1000 digits. My problem is that both in Java and PHP it says "Infinity". So the question is: is there any language and/or editor which allows unlimited high variables? I know this comes close to an off-topic question, but my question isn't about which language/editor is the best but it's about which language/editor is capable of it.

I hope you can help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with prime numbers, you need integer number representations.

The Python programming language is one that has unlimited size integers.